# Linking CSS Navbar WIth Wordpress Pages

Tags: php, css, wordpress, navbar

I am using wordpress as a full on CMS on a site I am building. One thing I cant seem to figure out is how to link up my navigation bar to the pages I am creating in wordpress. I am using a sprite image hover navbar that is defined in the header.php file.

Does anyone have any idea how I can take a typical CSS sprite navbar and link it up with the pages I am creating within wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically when developing a WordPress theme you will want to use the [wp_list_pages()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages) function to display a list of the published WordPress pages. It spits it out in a unordered list already hyper linked and ready to go. You can then integrate your CSS with it as needed. If you need further customization to the navigation, like excluding certain pages, reordering, them etc.. check out this plugin [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-navigation-list-plugin-navt/).

Another alternative would be to get your hands dirty with some PHP and other WordPress functions and create the navigation lists you need in your functions.php file.

Answer (score -1):

Does this help any? I'm only marginally familiar with Wordpress interaction but it sounds like this should allow you to execute PHP code, and thus pull your navigation somehow.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-execution-plugin/